# gdal_translate in R changing the cell resolution of extracted subdataset from HDF

Tags: gdal, r, hdf, gdalutils

I'm trying to extract subdataset from MODIS LST HDFs using following code.

```
library(gdalUtils)
HDF_list = list.files(path, pattern= "\\.hdf$", all.files=FALSE, full.names=TRUE,recursive=FALSE) 
gdal_translate(get_subdatasets(HDF_list[1])[5], dst_dataset = "sds4.tif")
```

But the Output raster (sds4.tif) is having different cellsize [929.378147, 907]. [926.6254331, 926.6254331] is the original cellsize of HDF file.

Comment: Not sure we can test this without at least one sample HDF - where are you getting them from? Can you share one?

Comment: Sample File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZQqF8IHds8uxHqevxTee4JQmZ8I3rOpU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Use gdal_translate with the -tr parameter

Comment: i have already used -tr parameter but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The HDF metadata has:

```
    UpperLeftPointMtrs=(7783653.638366,3335851.559300)
    LowerRightMtrs=(8895604.158132,2223901.039533)
```

and the grids are 1200x1200. That gives a cell size of:

```
> (7783653.638366-8895604.158132)/1200
[1] -926.6254
> (3335851.559300 - 2223901.039533)/1200
[1] 926.6254
>
```

Converting band 5 of your test file gets me:

```
> path = "MOD11A1.A2008005.h25v06.006.2015337154719.hdf"
> gdal_translate(get_subdatasets(path)[5], dst_dataset="band5.tif")
NULL
> b5 = raster("./band5.tif")
> b5
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1200, 1200, 1440000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 926.6254, 926.6254  (x, y)
extent      : 7783654, 8895604, 2223901, 3335852  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
data source : /nobackup/rowlings/Downloads/band5.tif 
names       : band5 
values      : 0, 65535  (min, max)
```

a raster with exactly those resolutions. So I can't duplicate your error.